# Compare multiple values from a DataFrame against a single row from another

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I'm trying to compare address values for inaccuracies, for example, given multiple records like:

| Reference | Apartment | Address | PostCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AS097 | NaN | 00 Name Road | BH1 4HB |
| AS097 | Flat 1 Building Name | 00 Name Road | BH1 4HB |
| AS097 | Flat 2 Building Name | 00 Name Rd | BH1 4HB |
| AS097 | Flat 3 Building Name | 00 Name Road | BH1 4HB |
| AS097 | Flat 4 Building Name | 00 Name Road | BH1 4HB |
| AS097 | Flat 5 Building Name | 00 Name Road | BH1 4HX |
| HO056 | NaN | 23 Street Road | XG9 9GX |

I've a dataframe where I store all the "main" addresses by checking if the Apartment column is empty like so:

```py
main_address = df['Apartment'].isnull()

df_st = pd.DataFrame({'Reference':df[main_address].Reference, 'Address':df[main_address].Address, 'PostCode':df[main_address].PostCode})
```

`df_st` will look like this:

| Reference | Apartment | Address | PostCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AS097 | NaN | 00 Name Road | BH1 4HB |
| HO056 | NaN | 23 Street Road | XG9 9GX |

`df` has over 1K records, but `df_st` containing the "main" address ends up with approx. 200 records.

I'm trying to create a new DataFrame where I can identify where the records don't match by domparing `df` against `df_st`.

**THE PROBLEM**

I try the below:

```py
# Clean the Reference values
refs_list = df['Reference'].str.split('/').str[0]
df['Reference'] = refs_list

# Create a new column titled issues and flag if the references match
df['issues'] = np.where(df['Reference'] == df_st['Reference'], 'True', 'False')
```

I want the above for the `Address` and `PostCode` unfortunately this does not work since `df` and `df_st` don't have the same shape.

I'm struggling to find a way to achieve a comparison between the two DataFrames `df` against `df_st`.

I want to compare all matching `Reference` row values from `df` against it's matching from `df_st` and if one of them don't match create a new column title `Issues` and store the conflicting column there.

**MY DESIRED OUTCOME**

Given the data above, after comparing `df` data against `df_st` results in a new DataFrame, like below

| Reference | Apartment | Address | PostCode | Issues |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AS097 | NaN | 00 Name Road | BH1 4HB | None |
| AS097 | Flat 1 Building Name | 00 Name Road | BH1 4HB | None |
| AS097 | Flat 2 Building Name | 00 Name Rd | BH1 4HB | Address |
| AS097 | Flat 3 Building Name | 00 Name Road | BH1 4HB | None |
| AS097 | Flat 4 Building Name | 00 Name Road | BH1 4HB | None |
| AS097 | Flat 5 Building Name | 00 Name Road | BH1 4HX | PostCode |
| HO056 | NaN | 23 Street Road | XG9 9GX | None |

Where `Address` appears as an issue in the column `Issues` since the address don't match against `df_st`, same for `PostCode` since it differs from `df_st`

**IN A NUT SHELL**

All I want to to know how to compare matching rows by `Reference` from a DataFrame against another and compare the other values `Address` and `PostCode`.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The best way to solve this would be to join the `df_st` to the `df` dataframe using [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and then simply compare the rows as you would normally in `pandas`.

Comment: Just to clarify: does `df` contain the true data? For example, for AS097, how does one tell if the correct address is `00 Name Road` or `00 Name Rd`? Similarly for `BH1 4HX` versus `BH1 4HB`. Is it correct to assume that we look to `df` for the correct PostCode or Address?

Comment: @Daren, `df_st` contains the correct data to compare against with, `Reference` is not a reliable data source, but `Address` in `df_st` is

Answer (score 0):

You can join `df` and `df_st` on `Reference`:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df, df_st, on="Reference", how="left")
```

Note: The `how="left"` would really depend on what you want in the joined table. You can then compare the values in the joined columns:

```
df_merged['Address_df'] == df_merged['Address_df_st']
```